# Creating my own Java Exceptions class

Tags: java, exception

I've created my own exception class

```
public class MyException extends Exception{

public MyException(){
    super();
}
public MyException(String s){
    super(s);
}
}


public class Main(){
...
public void setNumber(String number) throws MyException{
    if (containsNumber(number)) {
        throw new MyException(number 
                + " no number!");
    }
}

}


public static void main(String[] args){
    Main x= new Main();
    x.setNumber("028347987H");
}
}
```

My code won't compile. The main method expects `public static void main(String[] args) throws MyException`, which I already did in the setNumber(String number) method.

Comment: and you tagged this with javascript because?

Comment: Make your own exception class extend RuntimeException instead so your main method doesn't have to declare throws MyException

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> which I already did in the setNumber(String number) method

Right, but you *didn't* set that expectation in the method which *calls* `setNumber()`, which is `main()`.  The compiler is telling you that `main()` needs to declare that it might throw that exception, since a method it calls might throw that exception.

You'll either want to add a `throws MyException` to `main()`, or wrap the call to `setNumber()` in a `try/catch` which handles `MyException`.  Since Java uses checked exceptions, any given method either needs to handle possible exceptions or declare that it can throw them.